# Flutter ListView Image is so lagging when scrolling

Tags: flutter

When scrolling a `ListView` that includes asset images, It's so lagging and crash

I've tried setting `filterQuality` to `none` but nothing changed.

This is my `ListView.builder`:

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
    height: 200,
    child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: 6,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _hotdeal(index);
    }),
)
```

This is my Image

```
Widget _hotdeal(int index) {
    index = index + 1;
    Alignment _layout = Alignment.centerLeft;
    String type = "jpg";
    if (index == 1) {
    type = "jpeg";
      }
      if(index==5 || index==6){_layout = Alignment.centerRight;}
      if(index==3 || index==4){_layout = Alignment.center;}
      return Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            alignment: _layout,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/car$index.$type",
              //height: 200,
              //width: 200,
              filterQuality: FilterQuality.none),
            ),
          );
}
```

Comment: What about your image size? If they are too large and file sizes are too big, it's expected.

Comment: @EsenMehmet Thank you for your comment, I've check my files and it so big. Can I compress them ?

Comment: It's about third party things, so it has no bussiness here :) Now you know it's not about Flutter itself.